# Local Report RDLC cannot render with parameters in VS 2019

Tags: c#

I have the problem after change Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019 Community. No Local Report .rdlc in my solution can render. 
I have not caught any solution in net sources. Maybe problem of permission ReportViewer component or Reporting Services?

To make more clear my problem above I made some tests:
LocalReport passes in simple console app. If I add the same one as a testmethod to testproject in my MVC app solution, LocalReport cannot pass. Problem is in the Parameter collection. If I remove parameters from report and leave only Dataset there it pass, but with the parameters it ends with error.

Visual studio 2019 Community16.4.0,

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms 150.1400.0

Details:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=An error occurred during local report processing.
Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Report.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
at Mvc5_RepView_Tests.ReportTest1.reportVs2019b() in C:\VS2019\Mvc5-RepView-T1\Mvc5-RepView-Tests\ReportTest1.cs:line 248
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ReportRuntime.ProcessLoadingExprHostException(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ObjectType, System.Exception, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingErrorCode)
Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ReportRuntime.LoadCompiledCode(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.IExpressionHostAssemblyHolder, bool, bool, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.ObjectModelImpl, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportRuntimeSetup)
Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Merge.Init(bool, bool)
Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Merge.Init(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ParameterInfoCollection)
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.ProcessReportOdp.CreateReportInstance(Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext, Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandMetadata, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.ReportSnapshot, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Merge)
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.ProcessReportOdp.Execute(out Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext)
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReportOdpInitial.ProcessReport(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingErrorContext, Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.ExecutionLogContext, ref Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UserProfileState)
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReport.Execute(Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.IRenderingExtension)
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.RenderReport(Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.IRenderingExtension, System.DateTime, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingContext, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingContext, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.IChunkFactory)
Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CreateSnapshotAndRender(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing, Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.IRenderingExtension, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingContext, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingContext, Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.SubreportCallbackHandler, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ParameterInfoCollection, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.DatasourceCredentialsCollection)
...
[Call Stack Truncated]
Inner Exception 1:
```

**ReportProcessingException: Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Object type cannot be converted to target type.**

Ican't imagine what is the problem.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found some tips about this error : it seems to be a know problem and the solution is to upgrade the TestFramework package :

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unit-test-failed-microsoftreportingwebforms-localr/832174

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/mstesttestadapter-update-to-14-causes-filenotfound/684000

Best regards

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30710049)